# Why doesn't the text scroll with this function?

Tags: javascript, scroll

With this code the returned song name stays static

```
var temp;
function scrollon(f) {

 temp = f.substring(0,1);
 f += temp;
 f = f.substring(1,f.length);
 document.wow.display.value = f.substring(0,f.length);
 setTimeout("scrollon()",200);
}
```

while this scrolls as required

```
var temp;
var f = "Closing Time is now playing ";

function scrollon() {

 temp = f.substring(0,1);
 f += temp;
 f = f.substring(1,f.length);
 document.wow.display.value = f.substring(0,f.length);
 setTimeout("scrollon()",200);
}
```

Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change your code from

```
setTimeout("scrollon()",200);
```

to

```
setTimeout("scrollon('"+f+"')", 200);
```

since you create your function with parameter on it. You need to pass the parameter again.

Comment: Don't pass a string to `setTimeout`. The better solution would be `setTimeout(scrollon.bind(this, f), 200)`. Your solution will fail if the string contains a `'`.

Comment: @Sky both worked until I hit a song with ' in the title as Felix pointed out.

Comment: That is a usual problem on string. Example $f="Sky's Era"; function will look like scrollon('Sky's Era') which will not run since string was prematurely terminated by '.  One way is to replace the ' with ` use the $f.replace("'","`"); before calling the setTimeout.